# Evaluate a rational function at infinity

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, cryptography

In the context of the Tate pairing, I would like to know that it means to `evaluate' an $\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$-rational function at $\infty$.

For instance, the reduced Tate pairing is $e_n:G_1\times G_2\rightarrow G_T$, where $G_1=E(\mathbb{F}_q), G_2 = E[n]\cap \ker(\pi_q-[q])$, and $G_T \cong \mu_n$, the primitive $n$-th roots of unity in $\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$. Let $D_Q=(Q)-(\infty)$.

Then $e_n(P,Q)=f(D_Q)^{(q^k-1)/n} = (\prod_{P\in E}f(P)^{a_P})^{(q^k-1)/n} = \left(\frac{f(Q)}{f(\infty)}\right)^{(q^k-1)/n}$.

We end up with a Miller function evaluation, $f_{n,P}(\infty)$.

1. Is it obvious that $f_{n,P}(\infty) \in \mathbb{F}_q$? How would you even begin to think about this expression?

If we're working in affine coordinates, we can't even write represent $\infty$, let alone try to evaluate a function at such a point (at least this is what I have thought, but I feel like I have a knowledge gap).

Help with understanding this is much appreciated!

Comment: Ack, from the title I assumed you were evaluating a univariate rational function at infinity. Now that I've read your post more carefully, you have a function on an elliptic curve (represented as a bivariate function on the affine plane?), and you're evaluating that at the point at infinity of the elliptic curve!

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant to ask about, apologies if it was unclear before!

Comment: The simplest thing to do rigorously is probably to switch to projective coordinates, then back to a different set of affine coordinates where $\infty$ is affine (i.e. set $Y=1$ rather than $Z=1$). IIRC, for actual calculation, the result is wholly analogous to simply taking the limit at infinity, subject to the simplification what $y^2 \sim x^3$ as you near $\infty$ (I'm assuming Weierstrass form), but I don't remember the fine detail at the moment well enough to explain.